# How to use Change event for input array

Tags: jquery, arrays

how to use change() in array input and array select option

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#def_grade[]').change(function() {
        alert("hello");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array is an array of objects, just do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#def_grade').change(function() {
        alert("hello");
    });
});
```

The jquery selector automatically returns the array of object, each one will have the event attached.

Comment: Whats your selector for the objects? # is an id selector, do they all have the same id?  Did you mean to use a css selector .xxxx